# Split a python list without calling itertools' grouper function but get a error

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

In this code the grouper function works fine, however if I do it without calling the function. It throws a error

`TypeError: izip_longest argument #1 must support iteration`

```
from itertools import *

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


x = [1,2,3]

args = [iter(x)] * 2
l = izip_longest(None , *args )
#l = grouper(2,x)
print [x for x in l]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All positional arguments should be iterables, not fillvalue. [Pass `fillvalue` as a keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
it = izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)
```

If `fillvalue` is `None`; you could omit it:

```
it = izip_longest(*iterables)
```